# Is there a jest config that will fail tests on console.warn?

Tags: jestjs

How do I configure jest tests to fail on warnings?

```
console.warn('stuff');
// fail test
```

Comment: This article might help: https://medium.com/about-codecademy/proptypes-validation-in-react-karma-683c7d52abe#.zc36bwvk6

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a useful npm package that helps you to achieve that: [jest-fail-on-console](https://github.com/ValentinH/jest-fail-on-console)

It's easily configurable.

##### Install:

```
npm i -D jest-fail-on-console
```

##### Configure:

In a file used in the [setupFilesAfterEnv](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array) option of Jest, add this code:

```
import failOnConsole from 'jest-fail-on-console'

failOnConsole()

// or with options:
failOnConsole({ shouldFailOnWarn: false })
```

Answer (score 30):

You can use this simple override :

```
let error = console.error

console.error = function (message) {
  error.apply(console, arguments) // keep default behaviour
  throw (message instanceof Error ? message : new Error(message))
}
```

You can make it available across all tests using Jest setupFiles.

In `package.json` :

```
"jest": {
    "setupFiles": [
      "./tests/jest.overrides.js"
    ]
}
```

Then put the snippet into `jest.overrides.js`

Comment: I was unaware of the `arguments` keyword in JS functions. Cool! FYI, MDN recommends use of the rest operator, instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Comment: This technique will not work if there is code that is has `console.error` in side a try block that will swallow the error. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68463239/is-there-a-better-way-i-can-throw-an-error-cause-test-to-fail-if-console-warn-is

Answer (score 9):

For those using create-react-app, not wanting to run `npm run eject`, you can add the following code to `./src/setupTests.js`:

```
global.console.warn = (message) => {
  throw message
}

global.console.error = (message) => {
  throw message
}
```

Now, jest will fail when messages are passed to `console.warn` or `console.error`.

[create-react-app Docs - Initializing Test Environment](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/running-tests#initializing-test-environment)

Answer (score 7):

I implemented this recently using [`jest.spyOn`](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestspyonobject-methodname) introduced in `v19.0.0` to mock the `warn` method of `console` (which is accesses via the `global` context / object).

Can then `expect` that the mocked `warn` was not called, as shown below.

```
describe('A function that does something', () => {
  it('Should not trigger a warning', () => {
    var warn = jest.spyOn(global.console, 'warn');

    // Do something that may trigger warning via `console.warn`
    doSomething();

    // ... i.e.
    console.warn('stuff');

    // Check that warn was not called (fail on warning)
    expect(warn).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

    // Cleanup
    warn.mockReset();
    warn.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to post a full example based on [user1823021 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46678632/7295772)

```js
describe('#perform', () => {
  var api
  // the global.fetch is set to jest.fn() object globally
  global.fetch = jest.fn()
  var warn = jest.spyOn(global.console, 'warn');
  beforeEach(function() {
    // before every test, all mocks need to be resetted
    api = new Api()
    global.fetch.mockReset()
    warn.mockReset()
  });

  it('triggers an console.warn if fetch fails', function() {
    // In this test fetch mock throws an error
    global.fetch.mockImplementationOnce(() => {
      throw 'error triggered'
    })
    // I run the test
    api.perform()
    // I verify that the warn spy has been triggered
    expect(warn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(warn).toBeCalledWith("api call failed with error: ", "error triggered")
  });

  it('calls fetch function', function() {
    // I create 2 more mock objects to verify the fetch parameters
    const url = jest.fn()
    const config = jest.fn()
    api.url = url
    api.config = config
    // I run the test
    api.perform()
    // I verify that fetch has been called with url and config mocks
    expect(global.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    expect(global.fetch).toBeCalledWith(url, config)
    expect(warn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0)
  });
})
```

the `#perform` method I am testing

```js
class Api {
  constructor(auth) {
    this._credentials = auth
  }

  perform = async () => {
    try {
      return await fetch(this.url, this.config)
    } catch(error) {
      console.warn('api call failed with error: ', error)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the environment variable `CI=true` before running `jest` which will cause it to fail tests on warnings in addition to errors.

Example which runs all test files in the `test` folder:

```sh
CI=true jest ./test
```

Automated CI/CD pipelines such as Github Actions set `CI` to `true` by default, which can be one reason why a unit test will pass on your local machine when warnings are thrown, but fail in the pipeline.

(Here is the Github Actions documentation on default environment variables: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables#default-environment-variables)