# How do I make a jest test fail when the `act` warning appears?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs

Since the act warning is just a warning.  And in addition its stack trace does not show the test that actually caused the warning.

How would I make my test fail when the `act` warning occurs so I can lock down which test needs the fix?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a jest config that will fail tests on console.warn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28615293/is-there-a-jest-config-that-will-fail-tests-on-console-warn)

Comment: no because I have other warnings I want to keep.  I just want the act.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this package to your Jest tests: https://github.com/ricardo-ch/jest-fail-on-console

If you just want to fail on `act` warnings, you can also use the following setup in your `setupFilesAfterEnv` file:

```
failOnConsole({
  silenceMessage: (errorMessage) => /act\(...\)/.test(errorMessage),
});
```

Comment: Just `return /act\(...\)/.test(errorMessage)`, it's [already a boolean expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe ! Simplified this further to just return the expression directly.

Comment: I think we should return `!/act\(...\)/.test(errorMessage)` instead of `/act\(...\)/.test(errorMessage)` otherwise this ignores `act` warnings and fail on other errors.